# FB.ui request dialogs: how are the requests processed and how to keep it in canvas

Tags: iframe, request, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

Haven't done an app in a couple of years and I feel like I'm lost in the forest. :-)

Using the following test code in my app:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
FB.init({
appId  : 'myappid',
status : true,
cookie : true,
xfbml  : true,
channelUrl : 'http://www.example.com/myapp/channel.html',
oauth  : true
});
FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests', 
  message: 'Here is a new Requests dialog...'});
</script>
```

This, as expected, produces a list of my friends but after I select one and hit Send Request the other person never receives the request.

1) Am I supposed to process it in some other way first? Unless I'm seriously caffeine deprived I don't see what I'm supposed to do next.
2) Is there any way to keep the friend list box in the canvas page as opposed to a pop-up?

Thanks. I'm sorry if this sounds basic but, wow, sometimes the FB documentation gives you a glimpse of what you're supposed to do but doesn't give you all the info. It's like a programming version of flash cards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) your friends should be able to receive the app request (probably they just miss it / don't know where the app requeust is shown). see if they can see the request at http://www.facebook.com/reqs.php

2) make sure the user is login and connect to your app before calling FB.ui.  This can be done, say by using the FB.getLoginStatus method

Comment: I'm logged in and connected to my app. The other person is in the same room and, no, we're not seeing the requests at either http://www.facebook.com/reqs.php or on their main page. It's really frustrating that there isn't more debug info available.

Comment: Sigh..guess the documentation should make it clearer about the effects of using the sandbox switch. Just had a quick thought about it. Turned off sandbox and voilà, request went through.

Comment: i believe if the receiveer get access to the app that is under sandbox mode (e.g. he is a developer / admin of the fb app), he should still be able to see the app request.